# OpenVPN client freezes on connection

Tags: openvpn, vps, vpn-client

I have a network of machines inside an OpenVPN network. With no problem, I can connect into that network from my local machine:

`openvpn --config ./myconfig.ovpn --auth-user-pass ./mycredentials`

The problem is that I am trying to connect another remote machine (a cloud based VPS) as a client. Using the same config file and credentials on the VPS will not work.

[See here for similar issue](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/tunneling-vps-traffic-through-vpn-using-vps-as-openvpn-client).

Basically what happens is the machine freezes up. My current shell session stops responding. My only way out of it is to reboot the machine. To make it worse, if I run it as a service (`service openvpn start` with a config file in `/etc/openvpn`) I cannot even get back into the machine at all. Even after a reboot.

Maybe the connection is being established and it is cutting off my SSH? I'm really not sure. What I really need to figure out though is how to setup a VPS as a client to my VPN and still be able to control the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after MUCH more work into this ... I discovered that I indeed could get into the machine (albeit not thru SSH). When I turned off the openvpn, I was able to SSH back in as normal. Suspicion confirmed.

Then, the question became: how do I SSH into an OpenVPN client?

[I found the answer.](https://serverfault.com/a/660106/376630)

For anyone else having the issue, I am also putting the solution here:

```
ip rule add from x.x.x.x table 128

ip route add table 128 to y.y.y.y/y dev ethX

ip route add table 128 default via z.z.z.z
```

> Where x.x.x.x is your public IP, y.y.y.y/y should be the subnet of your public IP address, ethX should be your public Ethernet interface, and z.z.z.z should be the default gateway.