# Where to save ip rule, ip route and iptables commands on Debian Stretch?

Tags: debian, iptables, openvpn, iproute2, raspbian

To make an SSH server work properly while still maintaining an OpenVPN connection, I have a small mixture of `ip`-related [commands](https://serverfault.com/questions/659955/allowing-ssh-on-a-server-with-an-active-openvpn-client) I need to persist and run on startup on a Debian Stretch (actually Raspbian) machine:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i "${INTERFACE}" -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1234
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 1234 -j MARK --set-mark 4321
ip route add default dev "${INTERFACE}" table 1000
ip rule add fwmark 4321 table 1000
```

`INTERFACE` is a variable for the default device to use.

Where is the appropriate place to put these commands so that they are automatically executed when the system boots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian-based systems, you can find a package [iptables-persistent](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=iptables-persistent). This package enables you to easily save your current iptables rules to be loaded at system startup.

For routing related commands, you can execute them as `post-up` commands in the network interfaces configuration file. Here is a [related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321687/13810).