# SSH Session with Active OpenVPN Client Dilemma

Tags: ssh, vpn, routing, openvpn

Since this morning, my ssh session was getting freezed when I run `.ovpn` file.

The problem is that the default gateway gets changed by OpenVPN, and that breaks my current SSH connection unless I set up appropriate routes.

I found a solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/659955/allowing-ssh-on-a-server-with-an-active-openvpn-client/660106?newreg=bb894521bfe24be3a35ac9b23c5bf1c7). The solution is;

```
sudo ip rule add from $(ip route get 1 | grep -Po '(?<=src )(\S+)') table 128
sudo ip route add table 128 to $(ip route get 1 | grep -Po '(?<=src )(\S+)')/32 dev $(ip -4 route ls | grep default | grep -Po '(?<=dev )(\S+)')
sudo ip route add table 128 default via $(ip -4 route ls | grep default | grep -Po '(?<=via )(\S+)')
```

This created another problem for me. I can connect to .ovpn and have tun0 without freeze problem but when I try to wget a file I get `unable to resolve host address`. When I ping nothing comes back, seems like the solution caused me lose internet connection.

Here is the screenshot from `route -n`;

[image]

---

**What I do?**

I setup the server with this script:

- https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install
- or this: https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

Basically I let the script set it up for me. After I have the `.ovpn` file, I try to use it on another cloud instance and I get freeze problem. If I use the solution, no freeze but this time internet connection is gone.